# JSON Path Extractor : JSON Path Expression

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing

What should be the JSON Path Expression to get the beneficiary_ids of

```
beneficiaryType = OtherBankCustomer.
My Json response is as follows:
{
    "busBeneficiaryBeanList": [{
        "beneficiary_serial_no": 0,
        "beneficiary_id": "2090",
        "senderMobileNo": null,
        "beneficiaryName": "Shibashish Dash",
        "beneficiaryNickName": "Shib",
        "beneficiaryType": "WalletCustomer",
        "beneficiaryMobileNo": "9778697852",
        "status": "Active",
        "time": null,
        "accountno": "8093630503",
        "ifsccode": null,
        "bankType": null,
        "bankName": null,
        "address1": "testtesttest",
        "address2": "ewretrytutyutyityju",
        "address3": "fdfdddffr",
        "wPin": null,
        "randomNumber": null
    }, {
        "beneficiary_serial_no": 0,
        "beneficiary_id": "2113",
        "senderMobileNo": null,
        "beneficiaryName": "Girija",
        "beneficiaryNickName": "Girija",
        "beneficiaryType": "WalletCustomer",
        "beneficiaryMobileNo": "9861032490",
        "status": "Active",
        "time": null,
        "accountno": null,
        "ifsccode": null,
        "bankType": null,
        "bankName": null,
        "address1": "fdgfrhrgrbhegfbsdgb",
        "address2": null,
        "address3": null,
        "wPin": null,
        "randomNumber": null
    }, {
        "beneficiary_serial_no": 0,
        "beneficiary_id": "2102",
        "senderMobileNo": null,
        "beneficiaryName": "Sonu",
        "beneficiaryNickName": "Sonu",
        "beneficiaryType": "OtherBankCustomer",
        "beneficiaryMobileNo": "8093630503",
        "status": "Active",
        "time": null,
        "accountno": "12365478969",
        "ifsccode": "SBIN0000000",
        "bankType": null,
        "bankName": null,
        "address1": "qwertyuiop",
        "address2": "asdfghjkll",
        "address3": null,
        "wPin": null,
        "randomNumber": null
    }, {
        "beneficiary_serial_no": 0,
        "beneficiary_id": "2103",
        "senderMobileNo": null,
        "beneficiaryName": "kajal",
        "beneficiaryNickName": "kajal",
        "beneficiaryType": "OtherBankCustomer",
        "beneficiaryMobileNo": "8093630503",
        "status": "Active",
        "time": null,
        "accountno": "12365477777",
        "ifsccode": "SBIN0000000",
        "bankType": null,
        "bankName": null,
        "address1": "qwertyuiop",
        "address2": "asdfghjkll",
        "address3": null,
        "wPin": null,
        "randomNumber": null
    }, {
        "beneficiary_serial_no": 0,
        "beneficiary_id": "2104",
        "senderMobileNo": null,
        "beneficiaryName": "Ajay",
        "beneficiaryNickName": "Ajay",
        "beneficiaryType": "OtherBankCustomer",
        "beneficiaryMobileNo": "8093630503",
        "status": "Active",
        "time": null,
        "accountno": "12365477775",
        "ifsccode": "SBIN0000000",
        "bankType": null,
        "bankName": null,
        "address1": "qwertyuiop",
        "address2": "asdfghjkll",
        "address3": null,
        "wPin": null,
        "randomNumber": null
    }, {
        "beneficiary_serial_no": 0,
        "beneficiary_id": "2111",
        "senderMobileNo": null,
        "beneficiaryName": "devgan",
        "beneficiaryNickName": "devgan",
        "beneficiaryType": "OtherBankCustomer",
        "beneficiaryMobileNo": "8093630503",
        "status": "Active",
        "time": null,
        "accountno": "123456789012",
        "ifsccode": "BKDN0999848",
        "bankType": null,
        "bankName": null,
        "address1": "qwertyuiop",
        "address2": "asdfghjkll",
        "address3": null,
        "wPin": null,
        "randomNumber": null
    }, {
        "beneficiary_serial_no": 0,
        "beneficiary_id": "2112",
        "senderMobileNo": null,
        "beneficiaryName": "Sony",
        "beneficiaryNickName": "Sony",
        "beneficiaryType": "DenaAccountCustomer",
        "beneficiaryMobileNo": "8093630503",
        "status": "Active",
        "time": null,
        "accountno": "005013023756",
        "ifsccode": null,
        "bankType": null,
        "bankName": null,
        "address1": "Near Sai temple",
        "address2": "SBI ATM",
        "address3": "SS bihar",
        "wPin": null,
        "randomNumber": null
    }],
    "busPasswordPolicyBean": {
        "minLen": 1,
        "maxLen": 2,
        "minNumRqd": 1,
        "minUpperCaseChars": 0,
        "minLowerCaseChars": 0,
        "minSpclChars": 0,
        "spclCharSet": "#@",
        "pwdType": "SecretCode",
        "lastUpdatedOn": 1497433024653,
        "updatedBy": "1234"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your required JSON Path Expression would be like this:

```
$.busBeneficiaryBeanList[?(@.beneficiaryType=='OtherBankCustomer')].beneficiary_id
```

[image]

Comment: I need the beneficiary ids of beneficiaryType = "OtherBankCustomer" only

Comment: `$.busBeneficiaryBeanList[?(@.beneficiaryType=='OtherBankCustomer')].beneficiary_id`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following JSON Path Expression:

```
$..[?(@.beneficiaryType == 'OtherBankCustomer')].beneficiary_id
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Conditional JSONPATh]

References:

- [JSON Path Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. If I want to pass any one of these four output.. what will be the expression?

Comment: You can use [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function for this. Assuming you use `id` as the "Reference Name" in the JSON Extractor the relevant expression would be something like: `${__V(id_${__Random(1,${id_matchNr},)})}`. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) for more details.

Comment: Actually I am using the values of "id" in beanshell preprocessor as an input  to a method. How I can use different value of "id"? E.g String strId = vars.get("id").

Answer (score 0):

You can add Regular Expression Extractor

```
Regular Expression: beneficiary_id": "(\d+)
Template $1$
Match No. -1
Reference Name: b
```

You will get all the values stored the following:

b_1_g1=2090
...
b_6_g1=2111
b_7_g1=2112

Comment: I need the beneficiary ids of beneficiaryType = OtherBankCustomer only