# In Jmeter how to grep particular id value whose type should be matched

Tags: jmeter

My Json Data is {"statusCode":"200","statusMessage":"Success","responseData":[{"id":78,"type":"rijomon"},{"id":77,"type":"rijomon mr"},{"id":76,"type":"rijomon m"},{"id":75,"type":"testme","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":308,"id":75,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":74,"type":"Rittttttttttttttiiiiiiiiiieeeeeeeeeeeessssssshhhhh","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":309,"id":74,"item":"Ritiesh","details":"Nursery books"}]},{"id":73,"type":"Riiiiiiiiiiiiituuuuuuuuuuuuuuueriruwrhwqerqeqweqwe","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":304,"id":73,"item":"Ritiesh","details":"Document"},{"bc_doc_id":305,"id":73,"item":"asdf","details":"adsfasdfasdf"}]},{"id":72,"type":"Techv6","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":299,"id":72,"item":"Bike","details":"abcccccc"}]},{"id":71,"type":"Techv5","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":298,"id":71,"item":"Bike","details":"abcccccc"}]},{"id":70,"type":"Techv4","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":297,"id":70,"item":"Bike","details":"abcccccc"}]},{"id":69,"type":"Techv3","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":296,"id":69,"item":"Bike","details":"abcccccc"}]},{"id":68,"type":"Techv2","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":295,"id":68,"item":"Bike","details":"abcccccc"}]},{"id":67,"type":"Techv1","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":294,"id":67,"item":"Bike","details":"abcccccc"}]},{"id":66,"type":"Techv","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":293,"id":66,"item":"Bike","details":"abcccccc"}]},{"id":65,"type":"abcsdfdf","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":292,"id":65,"item":"Bike","details":"abcccccc"}]},{"id":64,"type":"abcgmail.com","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":291,"id":64,"item":"Bike","details":"abcccccc"}]},{"id":63,"type":"yyy","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":289,"id":63,"item":"11111","details":"11111111111"},{"bc_doc_id":290,"id":63,"item":"222222","details":"2222222222222"}]},{"id":62,"type":"Helathy","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":265,"id":62,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":61,"type":"Health12","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":278,"id":61,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":59,"type":"Other","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":262,"id":59,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":58,"type":"Susan vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":276,"id":58,"item":"Ann","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":277,"id":58,"item":"uiui","details":"yuiyuiyuiui"}]},{"id":56,"type":"tgerterting","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":232,"id":56,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":55,"type":"yyyyyyyyyy","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":228,"id":55,"item":"yyy","details":"yyyy"},{"bc_doc_id":229,"id":55,"item":"yyyy","details":"yyyyy"}]},{"id":54,"type":"sdsd","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":227,"id":54,"item":"dfdf","details":"dfdfdf"}]},{"id":53,"type":"dfdff","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":216,"id":53,"item":"dfdf","details":"dfdf"}]},{"id":52,"type":"fsdfdf","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":219,"id":52,"item":"dfdf","details":"dfdfdf"},{"bc_doc_id":220,"id":52,"item":"dfdfd","details":"dfdsfdsfd"}]},{"id":51,"type":"annmary","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":225,"id":51,"item":"erwerwe","details":"rwerwerer"},{"bc_doc_id":226,"id":51,"item":"erwer","details":"ererer"}]},{"id":50,"type":"Annnnn","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":223,"id":50,"item":"ertert","details":"ertertert"},{"bc_doc_id":224,"id":50,"item":"ererwe","details":"rewrwerererer"}]},{"id":49,"type":"fghfgh","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":206,"id":49,"item":"ghgfhg","details":"hgfhfgh"}]},{"id":48,"type":"bnvbnbn","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":205,"id":48,"item":"bnvbnvbn","details":"vbnvbnvbnvbn"}]},{"id":47,"type":"Neeba","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":204,"id":47,"item":"ttttttop","details":"tttttttttttop"}]},{"id":45,"type":"ccccccvvvvvvvvvvvv","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":201,"id":45,"item":"vvvvvv","details":"vvvvvvv"}]},{"id":44,"type":"bbbbb","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":200,"id":44,"item":"bb","details":"bb"}]},{"id":42,"type":"Latha"},{"id":41,"type":"test"},{"id":40,"type":"Acne"},{"id":38,"type":"Anicient"},{"id":36,"type":"Life tIme"},{"id":33,"type":"&&&&&&&&&&###&&##&dfdf","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":196,"id":33,"item":"121`23123fgdfgdfg","details":"fgdfgdfg324234234234%(&*%^(*&^(*&^"}]},{"id":31,"type":"with out items and details"},{"id":30,"type":"Testing on july 6th at 12.10","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":148,"id":30,"item":"12","details":"12"}]},{"id":29,"type":"2112424242424f","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":197,"id":29,"item":"ddddddd","details":"dddddd"}]},{"id":27,"type":"Coverage testing on July 7th","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":259,"id":27,"item":"66666","details":"666666666"}]},{"id":26,"type":"Coverage testing on July 6th","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":123,"id":26,"item":"66666","details":"666666666"}]},{"id":25,"type":"Coverage testing on July 8th","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":260,"id":25,"item":"66666","details":"666666666"}]},{"id":23,"type":"abcd","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":187,"id":23,"item":"jjhfsj","details":"njdjdaskjf"}]},{"id":22,"type":"Health","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":88,"id":22,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":19,"type":"Electronics","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":139,"id":19,"item":"","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":140,"id":19,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":18,"type":"Other Supplementary"},{"id":17,"type":"Cancer","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":108,"id":17,"item":"Hyd","details":"Biryani"},{"bc_doc_id":109,"id":17,"item":"Bellary","details":"Bhel"},{"bc_doc_id":110,"id":17,"item":"karnataka","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":111,"id":17,"item":"Karnataka","details":""}]},{"id":16,"type":"Critical Illness","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":193,"id":16,"item":"saasdas","details":"safasfasf"},{"bc_doc_id":194,"id":16,"item":"asfasfas","details":"afsasfasa"}]},{"id":15,"type":"Group Voluntary Long Term Disability"},{"id":14,"type":"Group Long Term Disability","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":261,"id":14,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":13,"type":"Group Short Term Disability (Self InsuredASO)","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":234,"id":13,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":12,"type":"Group Short Term Disability (Fully Insured)","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":5,"id":12,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":11,"type":"Group Voluntary Life Insurance","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":24,"id":11,"item":"rwerwerwe","details":"ererwerwerwerr"},{"bc_doc_id":25,"id":11,"item":"asdasd","details":"tyrty"},{"bc_doc_id":26,"id":11,"item":"dsfsd","details":"u7786"},{"bc_doc_id":27,"id":11,"item":"345345","details":"45634"}]},{"id":10,"type":"Group Life Insurance","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":76,"id":10,"item":"Test","details":"anu"},{"bc_doc_id":77,"id":10,"item":"sdbkjs","details":"mvsd"},{"bc_doc_id":78,"id":10,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":9,"type":"Vision (Self Insured ASO)","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":300,"id":9,"item":"Document1","details":"Document for the vision"}]},{"id":8,"type":"Vision (Fully Insured)","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":303,"id":8,"item":"Document2","details":"jdiksauasjfiaskfdasjfdasfd"}]},{"id":7,"type":"Dental (Self InsuredASO)","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":236,"id":7,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":6,"type":"Dental (Fully Insured)","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":79,"id":6,"item":"Dental","details":"Provide your payslip"},{"bc_doc_id":80,"id":6,"item":"","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":81,"id":6,"item":"","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":82,"id":6,"item":"","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":83,"id":6,"item":"","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":84,"id":6,"item":"","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":85,"id":6,"item":"","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":86,"id":6,"item":"","details":""},{"bc_doc_id":87,"id":6,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":5,"type":"Pharmacy Benefit Manager (PBM)"},{"id":4,"type":"Third Party Administrator (TPA)"},{"id":3,"type":"Reinsurance Stop Loss","coverage_docs":[{"bc_doc_id":231,"id":3,"item":"","details":""}]},{"id":2,"type":"Medical  (Self Insured)"},{"id":1,"type":"Medical
  (Fully Insured)"}]}

I need to get the id value based on type value using regular expression extractor or by other way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Path Extractor : JSON Path Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458317/json-path-extractor-json-path-expression)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It was so helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could use this JSON Path Expression:

> $.responseData[?(@.type=='rijomon')].id

and modify

> @.type=='**rijomon**'

to meet your needs.

You can get more info about JsonExtractor [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor).